# "Water and milk is/are"

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

When do we use a collection of uncountable nouns? Which form of the verb should we use? Singular or plural?

E.g.:

1. *"Water and milk is/are essential."*
2. *"Courage and bravery is/are slightly different."*

Answer (score 1):

When there are multiple things use the plural form:

- Water is essential.
- Milk is essential.
- Water and milk are essential.
- Courage and bravery are slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

> Water and milk is/are essential.

There are two different meanings here.

---

1. *Water and milk are essential.* This means that we die (or suffer) unless we have both water and milk available separately.

[image]

---

2. *Water and milk is essential.* This says that a *mixture* of water and milk is essential.

[image]

---

> Courage and bravery is/are slightly different.

3. *Courage and bravery are slightly different.* This has the obvious meaning that the two qualities are not exactly the same.
4. *Courage and bravery is slightly different.* This seems to have no meaning - different to *what*???